# Error "Reverse for 'auth_password_change' not found"

Tags: python, django

I am trying to enable users to change their passwords in django-helpdesk. In the [docs](https://django-helpdesk.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.x/settings.html), this is done by adding this to settings.py:

```
HELPDESK_SHOW_CHANGE_PASSWORD = True
```

Doing so results in the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /helpdesk/tickets/
Reverse for 'auth_password_change' not found. 'auth_password_change' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

And points to line 75 in

```
python2.7/site-packages/helpdesk/templates/helpdesk/navigation.html
```

which reads:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'auth_password_change' %}"><i class="fa fa-user-secret fa-fw"></i> {% trans "Change password" %}</a></li>
```

Is this a Django-helpdesk bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It [looks as if](https://github.com/django-helpdesk/django-helpdesk/blob/47c1a7b1c3d7112242c9359d3813cb414b95af89/helpdesk/urls.py#L185) the helpdesk urls.py includes url for login and logout, but not for resetting the password.

The easiest way to include the password reset urls is to include the `django.contrib.auth.urls` in your project's `urls.py`.

```
url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

See the Django docs for [Authentication Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) for more info.